# AWS CDK: Print Secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm creating a Secret in CDK like so:

```js
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs";
import * as apiGw from "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway";
import * as secretsmanager from "@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager";

export class ObjectCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "MasterSecret");
    const handler = new lambda.NodejsFunction(this, "HelloHandler", {
      entry: "lambda/hello.ts",
      bundling: {
        nodeModules: ["uuid"],
      },
      environment: {
        MASTER_SECRET: secret.secretValue.toString(),
      },
    });

    new apiGw.LambdaRestApi(this, "Endpoint", {
      handler,
    });
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "MasterSecretValue", {
      value: secret.secretValue.toString(),
    });
  }
}
```

And I want to use that secret to make authorized requests to my lambda function. The only solution I could come up with is to put a log in the lambda code and check the AWS logs online to copy the secret. Surely there's another way?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "make authorized requests to my lambda function"?

Comment: I want to use it as a secret when posting to that lambda function. The function checks a request parameter against that secret

Comment: The Secret will be available in the lambda function using the method shown in the answer. You can also check anything POSTed from API Gateway within the lambda function

Comment: That's not the question. I want to know the secret on the machine I'm creating the deployment from, so that I can use it when POSTing to the lambda

Comment: Use the aws sdk to get the secret value.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pass the secret value to your lambda function as an environment variable, try passing the secret name, and get the secret value from within the lambda using [`getSecretValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html#getSecretValue-property)

```js
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs";
import * as apiGw from "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway";
import * as secretsmanager from "@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager";

export class ObjectCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "MasterSecret");
    const handler = new lambda.NodejsFunction(this, "HelloHandler", {
      entry: "lambda/hello.ts",
      bundling: {
        nodeModules: ["uuid"],
      },
      environment: {
        MASTER_SECRET_NAME: secret.secretName,
      },
    });
    secret.grantRead(handler.role);

    new apiGw.LambdaRestApi(this, "Endpoint", {
      handler,
    });
  }
}
```

Then somewhere inside `lambda/hello.ts`

```js
const SECRET_NAME = process.env.MASTER_SECRET_NAME

const params = {
    SecretId: SECRET_NAME, 
};
secretsmanager.getSecretValue(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but as far as I can tell, this improves my code but still doesn't answer the initial question? Logging inside the lambda function already works